In a beamer presentation using includeonlyframes and overlays, how to correctly set the frame number?
This question is very similar to another on this forum, except I am using overlays.
I have a main big TeX file where I put all my frames. Depending on the presentation, I mix and match the frames using includeonlyframes. However, I cannot get a "correct" frame numbering in the foot line. For example,
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\includeonlyframes{topic2}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=topic1]\frametitle{Topic 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=topic2]\frametitle{Topic 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Point 1 \pause{}
    \item Point 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

The compiled PDF starts with frame number 2. But I want it to start at 1.

If I follow the solution linked above to use page numbers instead of frame numbers, although the compiled PDF correctly starts at 1, the overlay (?) adding the second itemize item incorrectly increments the numbering (I want the numbering to stay at 1.)



Please provide a small example showing what goes wrong, and explain what you want to have differently. From your description, I don't understand what you meant by "accurate frame numbering", "page numbers changing with overlays", and "frame numberings like Power Point". In my Beamer presentations, the page number does not change with every overlay, so it must have to do something with how you generate the overlays; therefore please include a sample document illustrating what you mean.

can you please tell us how powerpoint does frame numbering? telling me you want something done in the same way as an application I have never used, do not have and cannot run on my system without installing a proprietary os is not the most informative way to set out your desiderata.

Most themes will show the frame numbering and not the pagenumbering. Please add a reproducible example which shows the problem you face.

Apologies for omitting the MWE --- I was in a rush. I've added an appropriate MWE with this latest edit.

No idea what PowerPoint does with frame numbers or anything else, but you can easily add frame numbers to your slides in any number of ways. For example, you can simply choose an outer theme which includes the frame number such as infolines.
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  1-1
  \pause
  1-2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  2-3
  \pause
  2-4
\end{frame}
\end{document}

The numbers in the content are just filler. The frame numbers are shown in the bottom right corner of the slides i.e. the right end of the footer.





Try the following (no guarantees that this won't break things and don't combine this with unnumbered frames):
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@checkifinlist#1,#2\relax{%
  \def\beamer@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\beamer@temp\beamer@againname\else
    \def\beamer@temp{#2}%
    \ifx\beamer@temp\@empty
      \gdef\beamer@whichframes{all:0}%
      \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}%
    \else%
      \beamer@checkifinlist#2\relax%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\includeonlyframes{topic2}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=topic1]\frametitle{Topic 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=topic2]\frametitle{Topic 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Point 1 \pause{}
    \item Point 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=topic3]\frametitle{Topic 3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


